# If I create an AWS account in AWS organizations, can I delete it from my root account which owns the organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

There are various ways to automate [account creation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-organizations-to-automate-end-to-end-account-creation/) in AWS Organizations, but what about delete/close?

So far it looks like I have to login with the child account's `root` account to be able to close the account. Is there anyway to close a member account using the parent root? It seems like this should be possible.

Comment: I suspect AWS does have a way to do this and that you need to contact them because in one of the talks at Re-Invent there is a customer with > 16k accounts and they say they do automated deletion and creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time this is the only way, the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/) states the following.

> To close an account, you must be signed in as the AWS account root user of the account. If you sign in to an account with an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user or role, you can't close the account.

This will primarily be for security reasons, the exact same reason why IAM users cannot access billing (unless the root user allows it).

Comment: I have even tried enabling billing though, it seems you must be logged in with the root account.